# How do check node js errors in Azure

Tags: azure

I've deployed an app (node js backned and react on frontend) via a bitbucket pipeline to Azure. It executes without any errors.

```
pipelines:
  branches:
    master:
      - step:
          name: Install, build, test & deploy
          caches:
            - node
          script: # Modify the commands below to build your repository.
            - apt-get update || true && apt-get install zip
            - cd backend && npm ci && npm run build && cd ../frontend && npm ci && npm run build && cd ../
            - mv frontend/build backend/dist/
            - cd backend && zip -r build-$BITBUCKET_BUILD_NUMBER.zip *
            - curl -v -X POST -u $DEPLOY_USER:$DEPLOY_PASSWORD https://$DEPLOY_URL.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/zipdeploy -T "build-$BITBUCKET_BUILD_NUMBER.zip"
```

my package json

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "npm run build:app",
    "build:app": "tsc",
    "dev": "NODE_ENV=development tsnd --respawn --transpileOnly ./index.ts",
    "lint": "tslint -c tslint.json './**/*.ts'",
    "lint:fix": "tslint -c tslint.json './**/*.ts' --fix",
    "start": "NODE_ENV=production node dist/server.js",
    "start:staging": "NODE_ENV=staging ts-node ./index.ts",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
```

The site gives a 403 with "You do not have permission to view this directory or page."

I've downloaded the logs (diagnostic dump) from https://xxx.scm.azurewebsites.net/ but I don't find any errors.

Im running this on windows in Azure and Mac locally. Probably something wrong there. Can I somehow see the output from when then node app starts? Or how can I debug this?

Comment: Where the directory located? blob storage? there might be a permissions issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Starting the web app:**

403 generally shows up in Appservice when ever the application has not started. To fix this, in your app service click on **Advanced Tools** under **Development Tools**

This opens up a window with an option on top of the header - **Bash**. Click on that.

By default it will be in home directory. Now, using cd navigate to **site** -> **wwwroot**

here, you should be able to see all your files if properly deployed. Now issue the command npm start (or any custom command)

**Monitoring Logs:**

In your webapp under **monitoring**, you have **Log Stream** just click on that and you should be able to see the live logs.

You can give a restart on web app once these changes are done.

Lastly, under **configuration** check if you have provided a start up command for the app service in General Settings. If its node, hope you have given  process.env.PORT to get the available port. Hope this helps!